# Run tensorflow on ios with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, tensorflow

I have searched some related questions here, but I can't find the way to solve my problem.

I would like to ask how to run my python script(which includes tensorflow modules) on ios app. Are there any websites that I can follow the steps and install sucessfully? or some useful documents?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be hard to do:

Although there are several apps in the app store available, in which you can run python scripts, I think you cannot add external modules there (but I not that sure about that). You could check [Pythonista 3](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/pythonista-3/id1085978097?mt=8), for example.

If you want to do it on your own, e.g. write your own python interpreter - but then please be sure to read point 2.5.2 in the [app store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements).

Comment: Thanks for replying, actually I have tried to use Pythonista3 on ios, but it seems that it doesn't support tensorflow module

Comment: You might ask them Pythonista developers if they plan to include that module.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try other way to solve my issue!